Measure to receive data base on filters
I have following tables
Plant



Plant
Name




1111
Test 1


2222
Test 2



Material



Material
Plant
Index
Date




1234
1111
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.01.2024


1234
2222
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.01.2024


1334
1111
CopperNorth America
31.01.2024


1334
2222
CopperNorth America
31.01.2024



RM Prices



Price
Budget
Index
Date




10.00
11.11
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.01.2024


11.00
11.11
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.01.2024


20.00
22.22
CopperNorth America
31.03.2024


30.00
22.22
CopperNorth America
31.03.2024


40.00
11.11
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.03.2024


60.00
11.11
Aluminum premiumEurope
31.03.2024



Reporting date



Date




31.01.2024


31.03.2024



Slicers are made based on Reporting date and Plant columns.
I want to compare if Index in "Material" table appears in "RM Prices".
In both tables Index is not unique in general, but after filtering base on Date in "RM Prices" and Plant in "Material" we receive unique Index in both tables.

I've tried to create measure
Miara = 

VAR MAT_material = MAXX('Material', 'Material'[Index])
VAR RAW_material = MAXX('RM prices','RM prices'[Index])
VAR Reporting_Date = MAXX('Reporting date','Reporting date'[Date])
RETURN(
    LOOKUPVALUE('RM prices'[Index], 'RM prices'[Index],MAT_material,'RM prices'[Date],Reporting_Date,))

Unfortunately it didn't work. I assume that this is due to MAT_material is not unique but I'm not sure how implement additional filter.

You may need to review your model.
You can try this measure :
Miara = 
VAR MAT_Material = SELECTEDVALUE('Material'[Index])
VAR Reporting_Date = MAX('Reporting date'[Date])
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(MAT_Material)) && 
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                'RM Prices',
                'RM Prices'[Index] = MAT_Material && 'RM Prices'[Date] = Reporting_Date
            )
        ) > 0,
        "Match Found",
        "No Match"
    )

The MAT_Material stores the currently selected value of Index from the Material table while the Reporting_Date stores the selected reporting date from the slicer.
Then I tried to filter the RM Prices to get rows where the Index matches the MAT_Material and the Date matches the selected reporting date.

